# Android Application crashes because of intent

Tags: android, android-intent, crash

I have 2 classes: Main and Study. when I press the "study" button on the Main's layout it should go to the Study class but the application crashes instead.

**this is the Main class Code:**

```
package com.example.geograpp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View studyButton=this.findViewById(R.id.study_button);
        studyButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.study_button: 
                 Intent studyIntent = new Intent(this, Study.class);
                 startActivity(studyIntent);
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

**this is the Main's layout:**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" 
    android:background="@drawable/mainmenu_background">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/study_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:text="Study" 
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:background="@color/black"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/about_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/game_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/game_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:text="About"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/game_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/study_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/study_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:text="Game"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exit_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/about_button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/study_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/about_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is the Study class code:**

```
package com.example.geograpp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Study extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_study);
    }


}
```

**This is the Study's layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Study" 
    android:background="@drawable/study_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="106dp"
        android:text="Choose a Continent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/worldmap_clickable" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is the manifast**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.geograpp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.geograpp.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.geograpp.Study"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_study" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The log cat after the crush:

```
09-04 22:54:17.176: D/dalvikvm(334): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 49K, 53% free 2551K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 135ms
09-04 22:54:45.306: D/dalvikvm(334): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 12K, 53% free 2577K/5379K, external 23321K/25369K, paused 62ms
09-04 22:54:45.396: E/dalvikvm-heap(334): 22216740-byte external allocation too large for this process.
09-04 22:54:45.496: E/GraphicsJNI(334): VM won't let us allocate 22216740 bytes
09-04 22:54:45.506: D/dalvikvm(334): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 53% free 2577K/5379K, external 23321K/25369K, paused 35ms
09-04 22:54:45.506: D/skia(334): --- decoder->decode returned false
09-04 22:54:45.506: D/AndroidRuntime(334): Shutting down VM
09-04 22:54:45.506: W/dalvikvm(334): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.geograpp/com.example.geograpp.Study}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at com.example.geograpp.Study.onCreate(Study.java:12)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  ... 11 more
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  ... 21 more
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1899)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:286)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:173)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  ... 24 more
09-04 22:55:01.926: I/Process(334): Sending signal. PID: 334 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is crashing because your apps allowed memory limit has been exceeded. The only way to resolve this problem is to reduce the memory footprint of your app. My guess is your entire issue is related to the background set in your study layout.

```
android:background="@drawable/study_background"
```

Images are almost always the cause of OutOfMemory errors in my experience. Take a look at the resolution of this image and try to scale it down to a more appropriate size for mobile. One way to test if this is the issue is to remove the background line altogether and run the app. If you don't see any errors or the error you do see isn't the same you know the image is causing your memory problems.

To explain how I came to that conclusion take a deeper look at the last caused by line in your stack trace:

```
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1899)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:286)
09-04 22:54:45.538: E/AndroidRuntime(334):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:173)
```

If you look its during a constructor call to a RelativeLayout and is running out of memory while it is trying to decode a bitmap. Higher up in the stack trace you see it causes an error inflating xml. This means that the problem occurred when the Android system was trying to turn your xml into java objects and draw this on screen. You explained you were seeing this problem when your code was trying to move to the study activity which would indicate that the issue lies somewhere in the xml for study activity. Your study activity xml only has a single RelativeLayout with a background set on it indicating this is where the problem lies.

Finally I'd like to point out you also have a bitmap set on the image view which could also need to be sized more appropriately for mobile.

```
    android:src="@drawable/worldmap_clickable"
```